# Retrieve data from an unknown child name with Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as the database for my IOS app. I want to retrieve data of several users from the database.

**Here is my database organization:**

- Users

  - UserID1

    - Location: value1
  - UserID2

    - location: Value2
- ...

I want to retrieve the location data of all the users of the database.

**The basic snapshot fonction**

```
    ref.child("Users").child("").child("Location").observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in

        for Location in snapshot.children {
            self.locationsArray.append((Location as AnyObject).key)
        }
        print(self.locationsArray)
    })
```

**My question is:** how can I retrieve all the `Locations` even if I don't specify (I can't) the userID that is the name of a child before? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that retrieves and prints the uid of each user and their location.

We can further refine our results with a .query

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for snap in snapshot.children {
        let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let uid = userSnap.key //the uid of each user
        let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data
        let location = userDict["Location"] as! String
        print("key = \(uid) is at location = \(location)")
    } 
})
```

Comment: If it answers the question and works, please accept!

Comment: I can not before 2min.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with Firebase to retrieve just the Location.
There are a lot of option, but I see two that fits better in your case:

1. Get everything from all users, and then manage in your code what you want;
2. Create another dictionary only with users id and location.

The second option would be like:

- UsersLocation

  - UserID1:Location1
  - UserID2:Location2

So every time you change your main array you need to change this too.

Comment: This answer is not correct as it's certainly possible (see my answer). Also there are a lot more options that what's presented here)

Comment: Well, actually there are infinite options I just listed 2 that fit in this problem. And as you can see, what you did is getting everything from all users

Comment: The question states 'I want to retrieve the location data of all the users of the database.' which is possible, your answer states it isn't and then says 'There are two options'. It should be clear for future readers that yes it is possible and there are more than two options. Also, you mention 'creating another array' but the second option listed isn't an array (Firebase arrays should be avoided in general anyway)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I'm sorry, I'll change my answer

Comment: Wonderful! Option #2 is awesome so an up vote for you!