# How to retrieve data from all the Users using Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a firebase databank looking like this(Json):

```
       {
  "user" : {
    "UVHpZfD60EWcYDbeV60ENqXaioA3" : {
      "email" : "thisisanothertest@gg.gg",
      "location" : {
        "latitude" : 37.785834,
        "longitude" : -122.406417
      },
      "profile" : {
        "alter" : "23",
        "geschlecht" : "männlich",
        "name" : "Mario1"
      }
    },
    "nEsKd9uIOnSmVuMbAK0K2X1Dz6A3" : {
      "email" : "thisisatest@gg.gg",
      "location" : {
        "latitude" : 37.785834,
        "longitude" : -122.406417
      },
      "profile" : {
        "alter" : "23",
        "geschlecht" : "männlich ",
        "name" : "Mario"
      }
    }
  }
```

**Problem:**
Now i would like to get the Locations from all the users (latitude and longitude) to place them later on on a Map. 
I can get the location for a single user realy easy by doing the below code. But how can i get the data from all the users at once?

```
 var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("user").child(userID!).child("location").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let lat = value?["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
            let long = value?["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
```

I found a similar question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651206/retrieve-data-from-an-unknown-child-name-with-firebase-and-swift.)

So i tried that code from the above link:

```
let usersRef = ref.child("users")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for snap in snapshot.children {
        let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let uid = userSnap.key //the uid of each user
        let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data
        let location = userDict["Location"] as! String
        print("key = \(uid) is at location = \(location)")
    } 
})
```

But with that pice of code i was only able to get all the email adresses. By changing the "Location" to "email". How can i go down one more node to access the "location" node and get the latitude and longitude of all the users?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled the `location` key for your dictionary:

```
let location = userDict["Location"] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Replace it with:

```
let location = userDict["location"] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

You can always put a breakpoint at the print line and see what your location dictionary looks like with `po location` in console.

Comment: i wish it was just a typo :/

Comment: In your example above, add a print statement after every line and paste what you get, e.g. print("\\(uid)"), print("\\(userDict)")

Comment: it was really just a typo :D omg iam feeling so stupid right now. Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your data `location` is stored as another object, so you have to cast it as `Dictionary` => `[String:AnyObject]`

```
for snap in snapshot.children {
    let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
    let uid = userSnap.key //the uid of each user
    let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //child data
    let location = userDict["location"] as! [String:AnyObject]
    print("key = \(uid) is at location = \(location)")
}
```

Comment: @Mario If you take a look at my answer since I copied and pasted the name of the key from your data nothing is wrong you basically tried my answer with a typo again.